# Jest: Action Creators Issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When testing action creators, I want to test whether the correct action creator was called and also whether the right action was returned

*action.js*

```
export const AboutUs = {
    getAboutUsContentSuccess: 'getAboutUsContentSuccess/AboutUs',
    getBuildVersionSuccess: 'getBuildVersionSuccess/AboutUs'
};
export const getAboutUsContentSuccess = (data) => {
    return {
        type: AboutUs.getAboutUsContentSuccess,
        data
    }
}
```

*action.test.js*

```
import * as actions from './actions'
describe('actions', () => {
   it('should create an action to getAboutUsContent', () => {
      const text = 'Finish docs'
      const expectedAction = {
        type: 'getAboutUsContentSuccess/AboutUs',
        text
      }
      console.log(expectedAction)
      console.log(actions.getAboutUsContentSuccess(text))
    expect(actions.getAboutUsContentSuccess(text)).toEqual(expectedAction)
  })
})
```

But I am getting the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAboutUsContentSuccess' of undefinedd

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a typo in your `imports`, the name of your file `action.js` is singular.

Just change your imports to: `import * as actions from './action'`